# How should a receipt of a tax nomad be formatted?

Tags: taxes, travel, relocation, electronic-filing, world

I understand that the concept of a "tax nomad"; i.e, a freelance who works with a laptop and relocating to different countries gradually (say, once a year or once in two years) is becoming more prevalent as time goes by as part of globalization.

A tax nomad is still expected, at least by its clients, to give them receipts for works done for them and that they already paid for (say, by Paypal or Bank transfer or Western Union), but because a tax nomad's receipt isn't formatted per the demands of a given country's taxation authority guidelines, one can wonder how should a receipt of tax nomad be formatted or be read like.

How should a receipt of a tax nomad be formatted?
A similar question would be, what do all receipts of all states in this planet share in common?

<sub>My question relates to both `provider-company` and `provider-person` interactions.</sub>

Comment: This matter has to do with tax laws. The use of 'formating' in the Question should be replaced with 'in accordance with the tax laws'. https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/business/vat/eu-vat-rules-topic/vat-invoicing-rules_en

Comment: I'd suggest to write your receipt so that it satisfies as many of your customers as possible. And be prepared to provide receipts to your customers in a format that meets their needs.

Comment: Q - Are you not providing them invoices? Asking as I too work in "tax nomad" capacity for global clients, and they simply ask for a general invoice against which they make the payment to me.

Comment: @Aquaholic by principle I do give a customer an invoice; it's just that I want to give it in some universal form and I try to understand what is the universal structure that isn't dictated by one of the hundreds different state tax authority in this world.

Comment: @Aquaholic BTW, per what you wrote, I think you can help many and myself with an answer expampling the format you use.

Comment: @JohnDoea - added the answer with the format. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Aquaholic I wish I could up vote but due to giving the bounty I cannot; someone downvoted both the question and your answer and this disappoints me much. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnDoea ... That's interesting. Though I'm not after the "points", but If you simply accept my answer as the "answer" to your question, it will solve all the issues :-) Click on the "Check-mark/Tick-mark" icon which is between the Downvote icon and the Timeline icon next to my answer.

Comment: @Aquaholic I use the network 7 years at least and have accepted about 1,5000 answers, humbly, so I know what should be done in that regard; I give the question and bounty more time by principle; I can assure you I will accept the answer that was most helpful and of course it's about people who need the help in general and not just myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Wish this platform had a way to share documents/excels via source code, but here is an image example of what I use as a universal bill.

Type/format the following in a rich text document Document and you should be ready to go.

[image]

### Notes

- I've been using this format to receive payments from all across the globe including the US, EU nations, and various Asian countries.
- Any audits at my end are served by these invoice records which match the payments received, and the same invoices also serve at the client end as payment outgo's.
- I had no issues reported by any of the global clients over the last 8 years.

Answer (score 2):

If my company hires an entity, they will want proof that they could deduct the relevant payment from their profits (from their VAT bill etc.) and they will want proof that it was legal to hire this entity.

So, they will want a bill providing that - and if the entity didn't supply that bill, they may not pay it.

They will only pay the entity in a way that they have proof of payment so the entity won't be able take them to court to make them pay twice.
Also, they might only require receipts in a format that their tax office accepts.

Where the entity is located doesn’t make much difference to the company hiring it.

Comment: `they will want proof that it was legal to hire this entity` how, for example?... It is unclear to me (and BTW, I'm not from U.S.A in case you are from there).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to put a damper on things, but you generally need to be aware of the laws of the applicable to doing business with your customers wherever you are and they are.

For example, if you sell things to people in the state of Texas, the state of Texas will expect you to collect sales and use tax and remit that to the state government.

If you do business with a company in Saudi Arabia, they will be expected to pay a withholding tax on your behalf.

If you do business with most countries in Europe, you'll need to understand the VAT requirements and whether you need to collect and remit VAT it not.

The simplest option is probably to find a platform like the Apple store that handles these things for you.

Comment: Sorry if I put a damper on things as well but everything you wrote I grasped as either unclear, too exaggerated or not appearing alongside a legal bypass.